Empty spaces in the IntelliJ Idea Profiler timeline
I see empty spaces in the timeline view in IntelliJ Idea profiler. Does someone know what they are?
The related Jetbrains page says only:

Red vertical bars indicate thread sleeping state
Green vertical bars indicate thread running state
Blue vertical bars indicate memory allocation events

What are the spaces between them? The duration of the allocation events?

My expectations is that threads are either active or waiting. I can't explain the spaces in between.
